# Select the greater ID from a table

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to select the best ID from a table and insert into a variable (which can be int or long). My code is kinda working, but it doesn't get the number that it should. Instead, it gets -1 all the time.

Ps1 - RXRX is the ID column.

Ps3 - I have already tried replacing ExecuteNonQuery to ExecuteReader and them I get the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader` to `int`

```
private int aux;

if(some condition)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Should get a positive number in the next messageBox");
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(RXRX) from tablee"; 
    aux = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show(aux.ToString()); //Gets -1 all the time
}
```

What is wrong? Sadly, I can't use the LAST INSERT ID command as the person can come in this IF before inserting any data.

**UPDATE**: Got the answer. Now it's working, thanks everyone:

```
if(some condition)
{
            MessageBox.Show("Should get a positive number in the next messageBox");
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(RXRX) from tablee";
            aux = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //Thanks Joachim Isaksson
            MessageBox.Show(auxiliar.ToString()); //Now it works fine
}
```

Comment: How about `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: I had tried that previously, but there is some thing which doesn't allow. i get the message: "Cannot implicitly convert type '' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) will return the single value of your count (or - technically - the first column of the first row of the result) which you can just convert to an int and use right away;

```
aux = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Since Sql Server returns an int32 for a count while - for example - Oracle returns an entirely different type, the safest route is usually to use `Convert.ToInt32` to get the value (assuming you're counting less than 2 billion rows)

Comment: Precisely! Thanks buddy, I'll update the post in order to help others. One question, is it a bad idead to use the same MySqlCommand for different commands? Like, changing the cmd.CommandText whenever I need?

Comment: @ArthurMFB Normally you'll want to dispose the command after using it for a query, so that it can clean up after itself in the most efficient way possible. I'd be especially careful about reusing it for less "main stream" ADO providers like MySQL.

Comment: I see. i'll start using it. Ty again.

Answer (score 3):

`ExecuteNonQuery` will not return the value selected from the db.

Try it like this:

```
    if(some condition)
    {
                MessageBox.Show("Should get a positive number in the next messageBox");
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(RXRX) from tablee"; 
               object readedValue= cmd.ExecuteScalar();
               if(readedValue != null)
               {
                 aux=(int)readedValue; //Will always get the value
               }
                MessageBox.Show(aux.ToString()); 
    }
```

Comment: I had tried that. I get the following message: Cannot implicitly convert type '' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in eoq.exe

Additional information: "Not valid convertion"

Comment: Ya, but still not working. The code compiles but when I run the program and get into the IF, it shows: "Specified conversion not valid".

Comment: What's the type of the `RXRX` column?

Comment: it's int. There I have the IDs.

Comment: Check the type of the returned object, debug the program and use `cmd.ExecuteScalar().GetType().ToString()` and based on that type cast accordingly

Comment: Never mind. I'll see if I find another method, as this doens't seen to work. Do you guys know any alternative if not last_inserted_id?

Comment: It's not int. I tried it: "if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == typeof(int))". Don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExecuteScalar()` instead. This is the method to use when your query returns a single value.

Answer (score 1):

[ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the number of **affected rows**. Since your query does not affect any rows the result is `-1`. (If you - for example - deleted two rows, the result would be `2`).

To retrieve a single result from your SQL query, use [ExecuteScalar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This returns an `object` representing the first column of the first row of your query's result.
If no result was returned, the return value is `null`.
If the returned value is a SQL `NULL`, the result will be `DbNull.Value`.

Comment: Understood. Wasn't aware of this pattern. Thanks buddy.